CSS animation with incorrect time ratio
I'm trying to execute the animation below, which basically consists of raising the lock, making it rotate and then going down. I would like this to be done proportionately. However, even using a much lower percentage for the descent, the animation seems to execute the first two steps in 2s and the descent in the remaining 2s.


@keyframes float {
    0%,3% {

        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
    3%, 6% {

        transform: translatey(-4px);
    }
    
    6%, 30%{
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translatey(-4px);
    }
    30%, 94%{
        transform: rotateY(1080deg) translatey(-4px);
    }

    94%, 100%{
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
}

.square {
    
    animation: float linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

div {
    perspective: 500px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.cadeado{
    background-image: url(https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/loading-sem-cadeado.jpg);
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    align:center;
}
<div class="cadeado">
<div class ="square"><img src="https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/cadeado.jpg" alt="" align="center"></div>
</div>




I've tried setting the proportional % to 33% for each step but it still doesn't work


Doesn't the second 94% setting get rid of the first one? i.e. it'll start descending straightaway., after the 30% time.

I have found that mirroring he animation to be helpful. Is this closer to what you were looking for?


@keyframes float {
    0%,10% {

        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
    10%, 20% {

        transform: translatey(-4px);
    }
    
    20%, 60%{
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translatey(-4px);
    }
    60%, 80%{
        transform: rotateY(1080deg) translatey(-4px);
    }
    80%, 90% {
        transform: translatey(-4px);
    }

    90%, 100%{
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
}

.square {
    
    animation: float linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

div {
    perspective: 500px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.cadeado{
    background-image: url(https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/loading-sem-cadeado.jpg);
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    align:center;
}
<div class="cadeado">
<div class ="square"><img src="https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/cadeado.jpg" alt="" align="center"></div>
</div>




Thank for the answer! Unfortunately not :/ I would like the lock to go up for 1 second, keep rotating for 3s and come down in 1s

Hold on I think I can edit @Leo

Thats it Matthew, Thank you so much. Just made some small adjustments reducing the time to 3s and adding another step to 0 to have a delay between the loops. Now i have a properly loading :)

Below the new code @keyframes float {
0%,5% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
}
5%, 20% {

    transform: translatey(-4px);
}

20%, 55%{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translatey(-4px);
}
55%, 60%{
    transform: rotateY(1080deg) translatey(-4px);
}
60%, 65% {
    transform: translatey(-4px);
}

65%, 80%{
    transform: translatey(0px);
}
80%, 90%{
    transform: translatey(0px);
}
 90%, 100%{
    transform: translatey(0px);
}

}

Glad to be of assistance best of luck!



@keyframes float {
  0%,
  8.33% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8.33%,
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-4px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50%,
  83.33% {
    transform: translateY(-4px) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
  83.33%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
}

.square {
  animation: float 4s linear infinite;
}

 div {
   perspective: 500px; 
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-bottom: 44px;
}

   .cadeado{
   background-image: url(https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/loading-sem-cadeado.jpg);
width: 144px;
height: 144px;
align:center;
   }
<div class="cadeado">
<div class ="square"><img src="https://www.qas.flyembraer.com/irj/go/km/docs/download_center/Anonymous/cadeado.jpg" alt="" align="center"></div>
</div>



These timings somewhat matches your query. For the first 0.5s the lock moves -30px upwards, then rotates for 3s and then moves back to original position in 0.5s. So a total 4s animation.
@keyframes float {
  0%,
  8.33% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8.33%,
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-4px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50%,
  83.33% {
    transform: translateY(-4px) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
  83.33%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
}

.square {
  animation: float 4s linear infinite;
}


Thank you for you answer mate, but the behavior i was expecting was found by @matthew

happy that your query was ultimately resolved,,, cheers. My goal was to give an idea. I updated my translateY from -30px to -4px. I think it looks nice now.
